# Почему parseInt() выдаёт разный результат в зависимости от типа переданного аргумента?

Tags: javascript

Согласно [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) `parseInt()`, эта функция:

> ...преобразует первый переданный ей аргумент в строковый тип, интерпретирует его и возвращает целое число или значение NaN

Тогда почему `parseInt(0100, 10)` возвращает **64**, а `parseInt('0100', 10)` возвращает **100**?

```js
console.log(parseInt(0100, 10))
console.log(parseInt('0100', 10))
```

Comment: Число `0100` — это то же самое, что и число `64`, это число `64` автоматически преобразуется в строку `'64'` и парсится обратно из строки в соответствии с явно указанным вами десятичным типом записи

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Вы передаете туда число `64` в восьмеричной записи - ноль в начале числа.

```js
console.log(0100);
console.log("" + 0100);
```

Comment: Но я же явно указываю десятеричный тип записи. И в документации сказано, что "...преобразует первый переданный ей аргумент в строковый тип"

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Первый параметр - **число**. "...-ичный тип записи" имеет смысл только для строки.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin вот полюбуйтесь: `console.log("" + 0100)`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил, спасибо.

Comment: @Igor на самом деле Вы ответили достаточно, но не все знают что console.log тоже приводит аргумент к строке, как это ни странно.. мой плюс уже тут